# How can I break apart a string kind of like bbcode?

Tags: php, html, forum

```
$input = "This is some random text. OH! Look at this link [link=http://www.google.com] google google[/link]";
```

Okay so I'm making a forum website and what I want is for people to be able to use tags like `[link=*link*]*text*[/link]` and I want to turn it into `<a href="*link*>*text*</a>`

I need it to break apart the string to turn it into an output of html. I've tried a lot of things but it's a little to confusing for me. Any help would be amazing!

Comment: `I've tried a lot of things`-> I am unable to see that. Post your effort in your question to make people believe that you actually tried something.

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function

Example code:

```
$find = array('~\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/link\]~s');
$replace = array('<a href="$1">$2</a>');

$replaced = preg_replace($find, $replace, $text);
```

Of course you can add more replacment to arrays $find and $replace